# java get last day in next month

Tags: java

I have variable nowDate type of Date and I want set variable nextDate contains last day in next month.

For example:
nowDate = 2013-04-16

So nextDate will contains 2013-05-31

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
private static Date getNextDate(Date nowDate) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(nowDate);
    c.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    c.set(Calendar.DATE, c.getMaximum(Calendar.DATE));
    Date nextDate = c.getTime();
    return nextDate;
}
```

Usage:

```
    Date nowDate = new Date();
    Date nextDate = getNextDate(nowDate);
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 6):

Similar to Xavi but one less line of code :-)

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try setting a `Calendar` to day one two months ahead, and then substract one day:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.add(Calendar.MONTH, 2);
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
c.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
Date nextDate = c.getTime();
```

As others have already pointed out, you could also just add one month, and use [`Calendar.getActualMaximum()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getActualMaximum%28int%29) to set the last day of the following month.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
Date nextDate = c.getTime();
```

Comment: why 2 add to month? Why set 1 day of month?

Comment: The reason to do so is to be able to substract one day and get your desired date. `Calendar` will take care of differences on month days, leap years and such.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

Very easy.

```
YearMonth.now()            // Get entire month for the date current in the JVM’s current default time zone. Better to pass explicitly your desired/expected time zone.
         .plusMonths( 1 )  // Move to the following month.
         .atEndOfMonth()   // Returns a `LocalDate` object, for a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.
         .toString()       // Generate a String in standard ISO 8601 format.
```

> 2018-02-28

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that supplanted the troublesome old legacy date-time classes.

Get the date.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
```

Better to pass explicitly the desired/expected time zone.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ) ;
```

Pull the `YearMonth` from that, to represent the month as a whole.

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.from( today ) ;
```

Or skip the `LocalDate` entirely.

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ) ;
```

Move to next month.

```
YearMonth ymNext = ym.plusMonths( 1 ) ;
```

Get the date at end of the month.

```
LocalDate ld = ymNext.atEndOfMonth() ;
```

Generate a String in standard ISO 8601 format: YYYY-MM-DD.

```
String output = ld.toString() ;
```

For other formats, search Stack Overflow for `DateTimeFormatter` class.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Using [joda](http://joda-time.sf.net) and cribbing off [sinarf](http://blog.sinarf.org/2008/03/last-day-of-month-in-java-with-joda.html):

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime().plusMonths(1);
DateTime lastJoda = dt.dayOfMonth().withMaximumValue();
Date last = lastJoda.toDate();
System.out.println(last.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to increment 2 months to your current month and set the date as 1st.  After that decrement the date by 1 and it will give you the last day of month. This will automatically take care of leap year, 30 days, 31 days, 29 days and 28 days months.  Program below

```
public class LastDayofNextMonth {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(2013,Calendar.APRIL, 14) ;
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+2);
        cal.set(Calendar.DATE,1);
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE,-1);
        System.out.println(cal.getTime().toString());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **[Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)**:

First Set the Calendar to the next month.
Use: `cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);`

Then Use **[getActualMaximum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getActualMaximum%28int%29)** to calculate the last day of the month that you set in previous step.

```
import java.util.Calendar; 
import java.util.Date;

public class Main{

    public static void main(String ar[]){
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        cal.set(Calendar.DATE, cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE));
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        Date lastDateOfNextMonth = cal.getTime();
        System.out.println(lastDateOfNextMonth ); 

    }
}
```

**[IDEONE DEMO](http://ideone.com/cXAUMc)**

Answer (score 0):

we have so many good answers, however all above answers have code like:

```
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
```

this code produce a little confusion because Months start at 0, so 1 is for February.

(Edit: The integer in the add() function is not the month number (1=february) but the number of months to add )

Answer (score -1):

You can do the following to get last day of month

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();   
calendar.setTime(date);   
calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Comment: -1: The OP wants to calculate the last day of next month, not last day of present month.